Read sharepoint list items using Python
I want to read the sharepoint list items using graph api. I have this code which allows me to get a list of SharePoint Lists using a access token.
from pypac import PACSession
session = PACSession()
headers = {
    'authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
}

response = session.request("GET",
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/xxx/xxx/BTADMCA:/lists?select=id,name',
    headers=headers,
)
response.json()

I have two issue with this is that I am only getting the list ids but not able to retrieve the rows in the list the second issue I have is that I am not how to get a new access token from graph api. I have MFA enabled on my account and I dont have client secret for sharepoint because I dont have admin rights. I have to login using a code from my phone and approve login in order to sign in
Can you please help in getting the graph access token and reading rows from the list?
Sharepoint link https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxxx/BTADMCA/Lists/Central/AllItems.aspx
I tried the following code to get the access code:
import adal

authority_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
client_id = "de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064"

auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)

# Initiate device code flow
device_code = auth_context.acquire_user_code("https://graph.microsoft.com/", client_id)
print(device_code['message'])

# Poll for token using device code
token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_device_code("https://graph.microsoft.com/", device_code, client_id)

access_token = token_response["accessToken"]
print("Access token acquired successfully:", access_token)

I get the following error:
AdalError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-afa3aa1fa6be> in <module>
     11 
     12 # Poll for token using device code
---> 13 token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_device_code("https://graph.microsoft.com/", device_code, client_id)
     14 
     15 access_token = token_response["accessToken"]

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py in acquire_token_with_device_code(self, resource, user_code_info, client_id)
    309             return token
    310 
--> 311         return self._acquire_token(token_func, user_code_info.get('correlation_id', None))
    312 
    313     def cancel_request_to_get_token_with_device_code(self, user_code_info):

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py in _acquire_token(self, token_func, correlation_id)
    126             correlation_id or self.correlation_id, self._call_context.get('enable_pii', False))
    127         self.authority.validate(self._call_context)
--> 128         return token_func(self)
    129 
    130     def acquire_token(self, resource, user_id, client_id):

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py in token_func(self)
    302                 self._token_requests_with_user_code[key] = token_request
...
--> 362                                 wire_response)
    363             else:
    364                 try:

AdalError: Unexpected polling state invalid_client



Could you include what API permissions you granted in your application?

@Sridevi how do I find that? I don’t have access to azure portal. It is only accessible to admin

If you don't have access in Portal, then you won't be having access to retrieve them via PowerShell, CLI or Graph API. Check with your admin and include API permissions screenshot of your app registration in your question.

@Sridevi I was able to find that. Please let me know if you need additional info

You have permissions of Application type that won't work with device code flow. You need to grant Sites.Read.All permission of Delegated type. Refer this MS Doc for listing items https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

@Sridevi how do I get that access token though?

If you are using personal Microsoft account, then it's not possible as these APIs working with sites are not supported for personal accounts. You need to use work accounts that ends with .onmicrosoft.com to acquire token.

I have my work account but doesn't end with that. It is for my organization. @Sridevi

Then it's not possible. Users created in Azure Portal usually ends with .onmicrosoft.com. Try creating one new user and generate token with that user account.

@Sridevi I don't have privileges to create another account.

import requests

# Step 1: Obtain Authorization Code interactively
authorization_code = "your_authorization_code_here"

# Step 2: Exchange Authorization Code for Access Token
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
data = {
    'client_id': 'your_client_id_here',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'code': authorization_code,
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost',  # Must match the redirect URI configured in your Azure app
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
}

# Make a POST request to obtain the access token
token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)

# Extract the access token from the response
access_token = token_response.json().get('access_token')

# Step 3: Use Access Token to Retrieve List Items
# Replace {site-id} and {list-id} with your SharePoint site and list IDs
list_items_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
}

response = requests.get(list_items_url, headers=headers)
list_items = response.json()

# list_items contains the items from your SharePoint list
print(list_items)


How do I get the authorization code interactively?
